# Json difference between explicitly setting a field to null Vs not passing that field

Tags: json

Can we detect this somehow in Json ?

```
{"a": null} Explicitly set a field to null VS
{} Not pass that field in at all ?
```

Json considers both conditions as null, is there a way to detect this difference ?

Comment: "Json considers both conditions as null": no it doesn't. In terms of Json these two are different. Some tools processing the Json may hide the difference.

Answer (score 3):

In the former case (`object = {"a": null}`), the object **has a field** named `a` of which value is `null`. In the latter (`object = {}`), the field `a` is `undefined` for the object, in other words the object **has not such a field**.

`if(object.a)` condition returns false for both cases. However, `if (object.a === undefined)` returns true for only the latter case. So, you can use this check to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: How can I check this using GSON ?

Comment: `JsonObject aJsonObject = ...;` **`if(aJsonObject.has("a"))`** check may be helpful.

Comment: How can I do this using Java and GSON ? I'm required to have the field defined always